# Вывод текста из input в div с заменой текста

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток.
Не могли бы написать код, где текст из **input** будет выводится в **div** и при этом, символ **{** будет заменяться на `<font color="#`, а символ **}** будет заменятся на `">`.
За ранее спасибо :3

Comment: Текст будет примерно такой "{FFFF00}Жёлтый текст"

Comment: Вам текст нужен или цвет менять?

Comment: @Khipster, упс.. Не указал.. Мне нужно, чтоб в div менялся {FFFF00}, на `<font color="#FFFF00">`.. Менялось как код, а выводилось как текст жёлтым цветом.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что SO не фриланс биржа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, не понятна цель, но ниже ответ на вопрос.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="source">
<button id="go">Go</button>
<div id="target"></div>
```

**JavaScript** (используем jQuery)

```
$("#go").click(function(){
    var txt = $("#source").val();
    txt = txt.replace("{", "<font color='#");
    txt = txt.replace("}", "'>");
    $("#target").html(txt);
});
```